# Date bug swift at 31 march 2019

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting this strange output in Xcode(swift), code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter() //"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

var valueDate1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-03-30 02:15:00")
print(valueDate1)
var valueDate2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-03-31 02:15:00")
print(valueDate2)
```

valueDate1 prints

> Optional(2019-03-30 01:15:00 +0000)

valueDate2 prints

> nil

Is this really a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: DIdn't they change (at least in France) from Winter Time to SummerTime, and it went from 2 AM to 3 AM directly?

Comment: Most probably the date "2019-03-31 02:15:00" does *not exist* in your timezone because the clocks were adjusted one our forward for daylight saving time.

Comment: @Larme: In Germany as well. I am already curious if DST will really be abolished in 2021 in the EU :)